# How can I keep changes in the index when I use DIH fullimport?

Tags: solr, dih

I'm using Solr 6.5 to index files from multiples ftp files into multiples cores (having one core for each type of document, like audio file, image, software, video and documents).

The situation is that I'm doing this to populate an app that in its front end has a social networking approach in which every user can add new tags or modify other metadata without restriction.

So when I execute again data import handler to add new files to my application, it erase the index that previosly was modified for the user and set up with the data-config default configuration.

My question: is there a way to tell DIH, if the id exists, continues without importing and just adds the files which don't have an id in the index? 
If this is not possible, can I do something similar in a different way? 
Thanks for everything!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are doing a full import with default settings. One of them is [clean, which defaults to true](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler#UploadingStructuredDataStoreDatawiththeDataImportHandler-Parametersforthefull-importCommand) and deletes the whole index before the import.

Try setting it to **false** and also look at preImportDeleteQuery and postImportDeleteQuery for even more precision.